# Convert dict to pandas dataframe?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have the following dictionary toy example:

```
d = {"id":666,"dp":[{"Value":"11","Key":"abc"},
{"Value":"88","Key":"kuku"},
{"Value":"99","Key":"lulu"},
{"Value":"John","Key":"name"}]}
```

I want to convert it to the following dataframe:

```
id  key  value  
666 abc  11
666 kuku 88
666 lulu 99
666 name John

import pandas as pd
```

I have tried to use `pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d)` but I am getting `id --> dp` dicts.

Please advise, is there any quick method/best practice to attack this kind of format?
I know I can do it in few steps (to create the id column and add it to the key-value pairs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`json_normalize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html), but repeated values are in last column(s):

```
df = pd.json_normalize(d, 'dp', 'id')
print(df)
  Value   Key   id
0    11   abc  666
1    88  kuku  666
2    99  lulu  666
3  John  name  666
```

For correct ordering use:

```
#create list of columns dynamic - all columns names without dp
cols = [c for c in d.keys() if c != 'dp']
print(cols)
['id']

df = pd.json_normalize(d, 'dp', 'id')
#change ordering by joined lists
df = df[cols + df.columns.difference(cols, sort=False).tolist()]
print(df)
    id Value   Key
0  666    11   abc
1  666    88  kuku
2  666    99  lulu
3  666  John  name
```

Comment: Please advise what is the right order for the keys? Here you put the key with the list as value first and the key with single value last.
What is the right order to do it? I have tested it and it seems that the long one should be the first. @jezrael

Comment: @SteveS - is possible create liest by problem columsn names? like here `cols = ['id']` ?

Comment: Sorry didn’t get your point @jezrael

Comment: @SteveS - answer was edited.

Comment: Why when I am doing ׳pd.json_normalize(d, 'id', 'dp')׳ it returns me an error? That is what I was asking. @jezrael

Comment: @SteveS - because `pandas.json_normalize(data, record_path=None, meta=None, meta_prefix=None, record_prefix=None, errors='raise', sep='.', max_level=None)` here it is `df = pd.json_normalize(d, record_path='dp', meta='id')`, if change order raise erorr, because `df = pd.json_normalize(d, meta='dp', record_path='id')`

Answer (score 1):

you can also try:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
df[['Value','Key']]=df.dp.apply(pd.Series)
df = df.drop('dp', axis=1)
```